# PHP when file exists?

Tags: php, curl, video, upload

first off, let me say I've had a tough time asking questions that are formulated in a manner that makes the Stack Overflow community happy. So, I hope this question is acceptable- I'm just looking for some help that I can't seem to find anywhere. Thank you!

I'm putting together an app that allows users to customize a video through a web form, clicks submit, JSON ingests into video software, which automatically renders the project on our server, and is then automatically uploaded through FTP, to `http://www.example.com/video-renders/`.

Let's say the file name the user specified upon form submission is `video.mp4`.

When that user submits the project for render/upload, would I be able to trigger this PHP script to 'watch' the `video-renders` directory for `filename = video.mp4` and execute the script to upload the video to Wistia?

Here's my PHP that successfully uploads a file (url) to Wistia:

```
<?php

$api_request_url = 'https://upload.wistia.com';
$method_name = 'POST';

$api_request_parameters = array(
  'api_password' => '<<my_api_password>>',
  'url' => 'http://www.example.com/video-renders/'.$_POST['video-name'],
  'project_id' => $_POST['user-project-id']
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

if ($method_name == 'DELETE')
{
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($api_request_parameters));
}

if ($method_name == 'GET')
{
  $api_request_url .= '?' . http_build_query($api_request_parameters);
}

if ($method_name == 'POST')
{
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($api_request_parameters));
}

if ($method_name == 'PUT')
{
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($api_request_parameters));
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$api_response = curl_exec($ch);
$api_response_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$api_response_header = trim(substr($api_response, 0, $api_response_info['header_size']));
$api_response_body = substr($api_response, $api_response_info['header_size']);

// Response HTTP Status Code
echo $api_response_info['http_code'];

// Response Header
echo $api_response_header;

// Response Body
echo $api_response_body;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make this PHP script as a long running process and stat the file periodically

OR

2. In your upload script, when upload finished, create a job and pass it to message queue, this PHP script can be used as a worker，RECOMMENDED.

Comment: Thank you, but #2 is not available as my rendering software (Adobe Media Encoder) has the FTP function built-in. What about looping the PHP script until `success`?